# How can I write an additional piece of code to add all my outputs together?

Tags: python, statistics, sum, iteration

So I wrote this code that returns the **mean** of the first three rows of a **file**.

```
import statistics
with open('data/normal_distribution.csv','r') as f:
    g = f.readlines()[0:3]
    for x in g:
        q = str(x)
        l = q.split(',')
        m = list((l[:8]))
        h = [float(r) for r in m]
        print((statistics.mean(h)))
```

and I correctly get the output, which is

```
100.177647525
97.27899259
100.2046613525
```

now I want to write an additional block of code that will add the outputs of this code together, in other words, I would like to add 100.177647525, 97.27899259 and 100.2046613525 together. I tried to do this by writing this up..

```
import statistics
with open('data/normal_distribution.csv','r') as f:
    g = f.readlines()[0:3]
    for x in g:
        q = str(x)
        l = q.split(',')
        m = list((l[:8]))
        h = [float(r) for r in m]
        print((statistics.mean(h)))
s = 0
for x in statistics.mean(h):
    s += x
print(s)
```

but I'm getting an error message saying **"TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable"**. so what changes should I make to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the values in a variable or may be append a list with all the values like below:
####Solution 1: Store values in a list####

```
import statistics
with open('data/normal_distribution.csv','r') as f:
    g = f.readlines()[0:3]
    sum_list = []
    for x in g:
        q = str(x)
        l = q.split(',')
        m = list((l[:8]))
        h = [float(r) for r in m]
        print((statistics.mean(h)))
        sum_list.append(statistics.mean(h))
    total = sum(sum_list)
print(total)
```

####Solution 2: keep adding the value to a variable####

```
import statistics
with open('data/normal_distribution.csv','r') as f:
    g = f.readlines()[0:3]
    count = 0
    total = 0
    for x in g:
        q = str(x)
        l = q.split(',')
        m = list((l[:8]))
        h = [float(r) for r in m]
        print((statistics.mean(h)))
        count = statistics.mean(h)
        total = total + count
print(total)
```

I didn't run these codes yet but I think they should work.

Answer (score 1):

`statistics.mean()` returns a float, not an iterator. You are actually printing this function three times, once each for your first for loop, `for x in g`.
Instead of using a second for loop, just initialise a variable and add each mean to it.

```
import statistics
running_sum = 0
with open('data/normal_distribution.csv','r') as f:
    g = f.readlines()[0:3]
    for x in g:
        q = str(x)
        l = q.split(',')
        m = list((l[:8]))
        h = [float(r) for r in m]
        mean = statistics.mean(h)
        running_sum += mean
        print(mean)
print(running_sum)
```